# HTML page for SSO hyperlink buttons not working in Microsoft Word login

Tags: html, ms-word, hyperlink, single-sign-on

I created an HTML landing page to act as a SSO landing page. When trying to login through Microsoft Word, specifically using the "Add a place" functionality, the HTML page shows but clicking on the hyperlink buttons does not redirect. I tried adding `<head> <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" > </head>` at the top of the html tags to take into account the type of browser Word is using but still it is not working.

Here is my html. I removed the URLs for privacy.:

```
<html>
 <head> <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" > </head>

<body>
     <div id="banner" style="background-color: #0061D5; color: white; padding: 10px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <img src="logo1.png" alt="logo banner image" style="float: left; width: 44px; height: 25px;">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="logo2.jpg" alt="logo2" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 950px; height: 300px;">
<table align ="center">
    <tr style=" font-family: verdana; font-size: 24px;">
        <th> Select Your Domain </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align = "center">           
            <button style="background-color: #008751; border: black; transition-duration: 0.4s;
              cursor: pointer; border-radius: 12px;">
            <a id="cust" type="button" 
            style=
            "background-color: #008751;
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 8px 80px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              border-radius: 16px
              font-size: 16px;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-family: verdana"
            href="URL_REMOVED&TargetResource=">
            Sign in US
            </a>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td align = "center">           
            <button style="background-color: #008751; border: black; transition-duration: 0.4s;
              cursor: pointer; border-radius: 12px;">
            <a id="custEU" type="button" 
            style=
            "background-color: #008751;
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 8px 70px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              border-radius: 16px
              font-size: 16px;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-family: verdana"
            href="URL_REMOVED&TargetResource=">
            Sign in EU
            </a>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>

<br>

<div id="footer" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;" align="center";>Need Help? </div>
<div id="footer" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px;" align="center";>Contact support <a href="URL_REMOVED">here</a>.</div>   



<script type="text/javascript">
        function getUrlVars() {
                    var vars = {};
                    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
                    function(m,key,value) {
                     vars[key] = value;
                    });
                    return vars;
        }

        function addTargetResource(obj,tr)
        {
                    obj.href = obj.href+tr;
        }

        function SetTargetResource()
        {         
                    var tr = "#target_resource#";
                    if (getUrlVars()["TargetResource"])
                    {
                                tr = getUrlVars()["TargetResource"];
                    }

                    var cust = document.getElementById("cust");
                    addTargetResource(cust, tr);
                    var custEU = document.getElementById("custEU");
                    addTargetResource(custEU, tr);
        }
        window.onload = SetTargetResource;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the hyperlink buttons to redirect as it does normally through any other browser.

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 20 years or more.